# Using python sockets to connect to server, receive data and resend it to server

Tags: python, sockets, netcat

I have this sort of a catch-the-flag assignment where I need to connect to a server and a port, receive data, extract the number that was given in this data and resend it. I'm guessing I need to continue doing that until some flag will arrive.

I've tried doing that with python sockets (which I barely understand), and came up with this code:

```
import socket
import re



#AF_INET for IPv4, SOCK_STREAM for TCP 
clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Tell the socket what IP and port number to connect to
clientsocket.connect(('35.157.111.68', 10172))


while 1:
    # Recieve 1024 bytes of data.
    data = clientsocket.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    # Get only numbers from string
    data = re.sub('\D',"", data)
    # Send our result to the server.
    clientsocket.send(str(data))
```

It's establishing a connection and receiving the data, but when it sends the number back it doesn't accept it properly and it does it for only one round (doesn't loop).

Comment: That's because you break your loop if no data is recieved. So the send call is never executed - and your loop runs only once. You can just remove the `if ... break` line, or use a nested loop to receive data.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried different variations of it, including removing this statement and still no go. I think there's a problem with the clientsocket.send(str(data)) command, because when I try to print data I can see that the correct number is in there, but somehow it doesn't send it properly